# How to keep one ImageButton pressed when the user press on it?

Tags: android, imagebutton

i have a ImageButton, and i need to mantain the status of the button as pressed when the user press on it, until the user press again on it.

I tryed with this code:

```
        portada.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            portada.setPressed(!portada.isPressed());
            return true;
        }                       
    });
```

But it doesn't works, because when i press the button, the button is changing from pressed to non pressed a lot of times continuously until i stop pressing the button. It is working wrong.

How can i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: are you aware of [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
ImageButton portada.......

portada.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) //esto es necesario para evitar que salte el evento muchas veces con una sola presión del dedo.
                    portada.setPressed(!portada.isPressed()); //invertimos el estado del botón
                return true;
            }                       

        });
```